# Disable WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime verbose output

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

When I run my Azure project I get every 20 seconds or so this message in my output:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready

Is there any way to disable these output messages? Like change the log level higher? I prefer to keep the output more clean for important messages like exceptions or binding errors.

Comment: Nope, I don't think there is a way to do that. Aside you could try searching for something like "Visual Studio Filter Debug Output" or so.

Answer (score 23):

This has been bugging me for a while; but I've finally found a solution.

You want to change the Tracing level for the RoleEnviorment from All (which includes verbose); to for example Information.

Add the following code to the beginning of the Role OnStart to switch to Information tracing:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.TraceSource.Switch.Level
 = SourceLevels.Information;
```

You should find you no longer get the Role check messages.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that message is produced by the azure agent/emulator. I don't believe its (easily) possible to stop that message since its coming from outside of your process. I'm sure there's like some hacks somewhere to remove it, but I'm not sure I'd want to go there.